# innerHTML seems to be the only good solution for this

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I have a function creating an HTML/CSS MessageBox where I want to display a variable (already escaped with PHP json_encode(), no XSS injection possible).
I want to display this variable in a hard-coded message, it is always the same message.
The message displays this variable between HTML bold tags `<b></b>`:

```
Message("Do you really want to delete <b>" + reference + "</b> ?");
```

The string passed to the Message() function will be added in a div tag and the only solution I have is to use innerHTML if I want the variable reference to be displayed with bold style.

A lot of people say "Do not use innerHTML it's not normalized", "It's a Microsoft proprietary function, it's not W3C and will maybe no longer be supported".

I've always used DOM methods but in my case, DOM1 myDiv.firstChild.nodeValue property or even DOM3 myDiv.textContent method will not work because the string is displayed as text only.

The innerHTML method has advantage to not escape `<>`characters with HTML entities and unfortunately I think it is not possible to get the same result with DOM methods.

I can't use document.createElement("b") method, it would complicate everything since in want my Message() function to get the full styled string as one parameter.

So my thought is that innerHTML need to be used in some case instead of complicating things and it is not a bad practise depending on how you use it.

Comments are appreciated.

Comment: The `.innerHTML` property of element nodes (ones for which it makes sense) is a documented HTML5 feature.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, does it mean it will be part of the DOM like Microsoft's XMLHttpRequest was accepted? http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml

Comment: the important point is that it's supported today in every modern browser that matters, including all IE versions, mobile browsers, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most discussion against `innerHTML` is tremendously outdated.  `innerHTML` is nearly universally supported (with some narrow compatibility issues in IE), is now part of the [HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html), is [much faster](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) than DOM methods (**EDIT**: or not, see comments), and results in cleaner code.

What you want to do *is possible* without `innerHTML`, but it's not pretty:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var b = document.createElement("b");
b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(reference));
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Do you really want to delete "));
div.appendChild(b);
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode("?"));
Message(div);
```

And you'd have to refactor your `Message` function to take a DOM `Node` (or an array of `Node`s) instead of a text string.  All in all, I'd say it's definitely not worth it -- unless you're targeting IE5

Comment: Yes, it's not pretty and more complicated too, it would mean you have to create the div node every time you want to display a message, it's silly! The div node is created in my Message() function, this tag is part of the MessageBox, so there is nonsense to not create the div inside this function :)

Comment: By the way I'm not sure innerHTML is faster than DOM methods with recent browsers http://jsperf.com/read-innerhtml-vs-innertext-vs-nodevalue-vs-textcontent/3

Comment: Well, you could generate an array of child nodes and use `Messsage` to append them as children to the div, but still, that's not too much better.  Your linked jsperf test seems to only use `innerHTML` as a getter, not a setter; I'd like see a test using it to *create* new nodes (maybe I'll make one).

Comment: Follow-up: looks like `innerHTML` is slower in modern browser for writing also.  The quirksmode test page has "test now" links, which indicate (for me, anyway) that DOM methods are now roughly twice as fast for writing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can read the soothing [quirksmode benchmark](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) on innerHTML vs. other methods.

Comment: DOM3 textContent > DOM1 nodeValue > DOM0 innerHTML according to this test http://jsperf.com/read-innerhtml-vs-innertext-vs-nodevalue-vs-textcontent/3

Comment: Quirksomde benchmark was done with Firefox 3 and Chrome 5, performances seems to have changed..

Answer (score 0):

I am confident that `.innerHTML` is fine to use. Check out the compatibility stats here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html and they also highlight performance gains of using this method as opposed to DOM methods.

Comment: Thanks but your test is old (Firefox 3 and Chrome 5), things have changed and DOM methods seems to have better performance than innerHTML http://jsperf.com/read-innerhtml-vs-innertext-vs-nodevalue-vs-textcontent/3